# SOAP in PHP (Ubuntu 16) - AWS. Not work

Tags: php, web-services, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, soap

I have a problem when i consume a Weservice SOAP with php from my instance in AWS (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1022-aws x86_64)). When I consume this service (http://fakeurl:fakeport/DynamicsNAV/WS/Company/Codeunit?wsdl) in my localhost, it work! but in production (AWS) not work and show this error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://fakeurl:fakeport/DynamicsNAV/WS/Company/Codeunit?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://fakeurl:fakeport/DynamicsNAV/WS/Company/Codeunit?wsdl"
```

Is there anything I can do?
Any settings I can make?

I already installed *php-soap* and I already configured the *php.ini* but not work. In DigitalOcean it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed this components in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install -y tmux curl wget php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-intl
```

After that I rebooted the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and worked out it was SELinux that was blocking the call - you could try disabling that first as a try...

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: A quick Google will help. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=disabling+selinux+ubuntu&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB726GB726&oq=disabling+selinux&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.10087j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8